# Kafka Class is not in the trusted package error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am trying to integrate Kafka in my project. I have 2 spring applications, one has to be configured as a producer and the other one as a consumer. I am trying to send a greeting message. Greeting is a class having two field, it will be seen below. But I keep getting this error in the consumer app console:

```
2021-11-23 13:31:53.412 ERROR 8452 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:194) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1598) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition greetingTopic-0 at offset 3. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'assignment2.kafka.Greeting' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer, ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
```

The code for the Kafka producer configuration:

```
package assignment2.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }


    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Greeting> greetingProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        configProps.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "greeting:assignment2.kafka.Greeting");
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Greeting> greetingKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(greetingProducerFactory());
    }
}
```

I have the following code for the Kafka consumer configuration:

```
package ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                "sensorGroup");
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>  kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    public ConsumerFactory<String, Greeting> greetingConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "greeting");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "greeting:assignment2.kafka.Greeting");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "assignment2.kafka.Greeting");
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Greeting.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Greeting> greetingKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Greeting> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(greetingConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And the **Greeting** class, which is present in both applications. On the consumer app, in the **ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer** package and on the producer part, on the **assignment2.kafka** package.

```
public class Greeting {

    private String msg;
    private String name;

    public Greeting() {

    }

    public Greeting(String msg, String name) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return msg + ", " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

I suspect there is something wrong with my configuration, I found a similar solved question here: [Spring Boot Kafka Consumer throwing error in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858489/spring-boot-kafka-consumer-throwing-error-in-loop) . I have added the specific lines that solved this person error, but unfortunately I cannot make it work. I believe it is related to the fact that I have two separate applications, so the object of type **Greeting** that is send from producer to consumer is not in the same package.
Thank you! Hope someone can help

Comment: Could you share your `Greeting` class, too, please.

Comment: @jmizv Yes, I have modified the question. You can find the code for the Greeting class now.

Comment: You are mapping the wrong type on the consumer side `props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "greeting:assignment2.kafka.Greeting");` - it should be the consumer greeting type there.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem modifying the configuration in the following way:
`return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Greeting.class, false));`
In the last line in the **greetingConsumerFactory**, I have added **false** in the **JsonDeserializer**.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the wrong type on the consumer side...

```
props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "greeting:assignment2.kafka.Greeting");
```

Needs to be the consumer version.

Comment: I have modified the configuration for **greetingConsumeFactory()**  in this way:       `props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "greeting:ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.Greeting");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "ro.tuc.ds2020.kafkaconsumer.Greeting");  `  but the error still appears

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Oh - you have set `ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` to false; it needs to be true to convey headers. But it should still succeed because of the default type config. Please post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace and I'll take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638846/spring-kafka-model-is-not-in-the-trusted-packages that I can set the **useHeadersIfPresent** from **JsonDeserializer**  to false and it seems to be working for me.